# Load xml tags into javascript array

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a  quiz in javascript that i am trying to load externally using a xml file.  there are 24 questions.  I want to load the questions into my the "myQuestions" array and load each answer into the a, b, c and d arrays.  The xml file is named MYFile.xml Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please and thank you.

```
<question>
<text><![CDATA[<b>Question 1 Text</b>]]> </text>
<answers>
<text correct="1">1Answer 1 Text</text>
<text correct="0">1Answer 2 Text</text>
<text correct="0">1Answer 3 Text</text>
<text correct="0">1Answer 4 Text</text>
</answers>
</question>
<question>
<text><![CDATA[<b>Question 2 Text</b>]]> </text>
<answers>
<text correct="1">2Answer 1 Text</text>
<text correct="0">2Answer 2 Text</text>
<text correct="0">2Answer 3 Text</text>
<text correct="0">2Answer 4 Text</text>
</answers>
</question>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [txml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/txml), the fastest xml parser in javascript?

```js
var xml = require("txml");
const fs = require('fs');

const data = fs.readFileSync('MYFile.xml').toString();
const dom = xml(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(
  xml.simplifyLostLess(dom), undefined, '  '
));
```

This will print:

```
{
  "question": [
    {
      "text": "<b>Question 1 Text</b>",
      "answers": {
        "text": [
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "1"
            },
            "value": "1Answer 1 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "1Answer 2 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "1Answer 3 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "1Answer 4 Text"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "text": "<b>Question 2 Text</b>",
      "answers": {
        "text": [
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "1"
            },
            "value": "2Answer 1 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "2Answer 2 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "2Answer 3 Text"
          },
          {
            "_attributes": {
              "correct": "0"
            },
            "value": "2Answer 4 Text"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm using Animate CC canvas which is basically javascript. I was looking to add all the question tags to the myquestions array then the others to a different array. I think the way you wrote it is a little over my head for the issue I'm having.